# C command line arguments input

Tags: c

[image]

Hi! So I was playing with command line arguments to get used to work with them. I tried to make the program to say valid if the argument I would write is the same as the one saved in the variable.
Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: 1) Please provide your code here and not in a screenshot offsite. 2) You are not comparing strings correctly. 3) You should check to see if `argv[1]` exists before accessing it, namely by checking the size of `argc`.

Comment: CS50 is horrible by pretending that `string` is a first class object with operations like `==` and `!=`.  It is just not true.

Comment: Question, if no arguments are passed, what is held in `argv[1]`? (hint: it is valid, but what is it?) Also, do not post PICTURES of code. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `argv[1]` with no arguments is valid in that it will resolve to some memory address at runtime, but as far as C is concerned it's still undefined behavior. I imagine you're going for the response "It is garbage data" which is the typical thing to tell beginners. The fact of the matter is it can be anything, and it can lead to serious errors and vulnerabilities in some cases.

Comment: @abelenky: I agree that this is a disadvantage of CS50's approach. However, overall, I believe that CS50's approach which uses `get_string`, `get_int`, `get_float`, etc. for user input is better than asking students to use `scanf`. By using `typedef char * string;`, students don't have to deal with pointers at the start. The true nature of strings is revealed to the students in [lesson 2 of CS50](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/weeks/2/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `strcmp` to compare strings.
In C, you cannot use `==` and `!=` to check for string equality.

What you want is:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], pass))   // Use String Compare (strcmp) to test equality.  
                             // Returns 0 if strings are equal
                             // Returns non-zero if strings are different.
{
    printf("Invalid\n");
}
```

Comment: Since the value being checked against is a constant I'd advise `strncmp`. It's also a good idea to use `argc` to validate `argv[1]`.

Comment: @h0r53: No argument.  But with a clear beginner, I'd stick with `strcmp` for simplicity, and discuss array-overruns in a later lesson.

Comment: Fair enough. Since the OP is a beginner I'll note that the reason that `==` doesn't work is because the values being compared are the memory locations of the strings and not the strings themselves.